# i18next and Expo with multiple translation files

Tags: localization, expo, i18next

I am attempting to use `i18next` with Expo, with multiple translation files however I keep getting the following errors:

`i18next::translator: missingKey en Common NextSteps NextSteps`

`i18next::backendConnector: loading namespace Common for language en failed, [TypeError: Network request failed]`

My config file is:

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

i18n
    .use(Backend)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        backend: {
            loadPath: './translations/en/{{ns}}.json',
        },
        debug: true,
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        ns: ['Common'],
        defaultNS: 'Common',
    });

export default i18n;
```

In my app screen i am using the hook:

`const [t] = useTranslation(['Common'])`

and accessing this with:

`<Text>{t('Common:NextSteps')}</Text>`

The translation files are in the top level at:

[image]

I can't find any clear examples of using multiple JSON files with Expo. Thanks

Comment: You need to investigate why the network request failed?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect expo, like react-native is not hosting the translations so they could be fetched via i18next-http-backend. So I would suggest you load the translations without i18next-http-backend. As resources on init: https://www.i18next.com/how-to/add-or-load-translations#add-on-init or with the help of i18next-resources-to-backend: https://www.i18next.com/how-to/add-or-load-translations#lazy-load-in-memory-translations

Comment: @StephenKempin, can you share the working example here? The GitHub repo is gone.